# OpenX upgrade results in plugin errors

Tags: database, plugins, upgrade, pear, openx

After upgrading to OpenX 2.8.8, I'm getting these errors:

```
PEAR Error 
DB_DataObject Error: autoload:Could not find class DataObjects_Ext_market_assoc_data using class_location value 

PEAR Error 
DB_DataObject Error: factory could not find class from ext_market_assoc_data
```

Can you suggest what I can do to resolve these errors or further diagnose the issue? It's on several pages, including pages that display banners -- but not on the live site.

TTFN
Travis

Comment: Travis did any suggestion help? Facing similar problem.

Comment: Also, I would like to add, that I have a different error message, but it is about plugins as well. Here's link to it http://pastebin.com/cHYGXvNE. Due to that I can't edit any banner code.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Just copied plugins directory from 2.8.7 version. Everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like an error in PEAR or its libraries, but with OpenX. Ask in their support forums.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having the same issue (as I had had in the past). 
For the first time ever, though, I just managed to have a smooth upgrade to 2.8.9.

What I did:

**MAKE SURE TO DO ANY BACKUPS AND TEST-RUN THE PROCESS AND DOUBLE CHECK FOR ANY POSSIBLE ERRORS. USE THESE EXPLANATIONS AT YOUR OWN RISK**

> [!] OpenX **requires** a file-path to the *old* installation in
>       order to complete the upgrade (it basically checks the plugins
>       in the old version and then re-installs them in the new
>       version). So you should always upgrade by having a clean/new installation directory, and not **replace** the current installation with the new openx files.

- create new database (openx_new) and give the database user permissions
  to the new database (don't forget to give access to LOCK TABLEs)
- dump the current database and load into the new one

> mysqldump -uUSER -pPASSWORD openxdb_old –skip-lock-tables > FILE.sql
>   mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD openxdb_new < FILE.sql

- unzip the new openx files in, eg, /openx_new
- copy the configuration file(s) and any banner/image files you may have from the old to the new directory
- adjust the configuration file in the new directory so it points to the new database created above (openxdb_new)

Here comes the switch:

- flip the directories: `mv /openx /openx_old` and `mv /openx_new /openx` ; now the new files are in the directory /openx and the old ones in /openx_old.
- go to the admin page of openx (eg, http://www.example.org/openx). After logging in, the installation/upgrading process should kick in.
- it may ask for some minor changes in the file permissions; fix them.
- eventually, it will ask for the directory where the previous
  version was installed; point to the "/openx_old" directory
  mentioned above. This will cause OpenX to check the plugins
  and re-install them.

You're done. Hopefully.

Ref:

http://www.openxconsultant.com/blog/2010/11/how-to-upgrade-openx-ad-server/

The article offers a way to avoid any downtime, I went ahead with just a few seconds of dowtime and 10 minutes of lost statistics.

Answer (score -1):

Don’t worry about this problem, I also lacked the same problem, at that time my friend refers to use the [openxmods.com](http://openxmods.com) plugins, they are different types and also all plugins are develops using latest technologies and development of custom plugins is also possible in openxmods.com. All plugins are easy to install.

If you interest to using latest openx ad server choose openxmods.com plugins. I assure that 100% confidentially, and also efficiency.